# Return all except some fields using findOne() in mongodb for node.js

Tags: mongodb, query, node.js

I am trying to use the following script to query for a document but the returned document still contains the field (password) that I don't want.

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect(
                      MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING, 
                      { useUnifiedTopology: true }
                   );
const db = client.db(DB_NAME);    
const collection = db.collection(collectionName);    
const data = await collection
                .find(
                    {
                        _id: someId
                    },
                    {
                        password: 0
                    }
                );
```

It supposed to work as I have read in the mongodb documentation but I didn't find any documentation on findOne in mongodb for node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is mentioned in another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15961570/6096591) to a different question. If I modify the projection as a value of "fields" as below then findOne() works as I expect.

```
const data = await collection
            .findOne(
                {
                    _id: someId
                },
                {
                    fields: {password: 0}
                }
            );
```

Comment: The answer works at the moment but it gives deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `project()`. See the example here - [Projections](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/tutorials/projections/)

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but, it seems, project() doesn't work with findOne() either. If I use find().project.toArray() then it returns an array, which I don't want. I found a solution to my problem; I think, I should mention that  as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use projection.
Which in your case is something like this

```
const data = await collection.find(
                            {
                                _id: someId
                            },
                            {
                                projection:
                                {

                                    password: 0
                                }
                            }
                        );
```